# Obiee column measures are same for different time periods

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I was creating some analysis on revenue for past years. One thing I noticed is measures of revenue for each month of a year are same for every year's corresponding months. That is revenue for April 2015 is same as revenue for April 2016.

I did some searching to solve this problem. I found that our measure column `'Revenue'` is aggreagted based on time dimension as `'Last(sum(revenue))'`. So actual revenue values of April 2019 is considered by OBIEE as last and copied to other year's April month revenue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can understand that keyword `'last'` may be the reason of this, but shouldn't `year, quarter, month` columns choose exactly those numbers that corresponds to that date? Can someone explain how this works and suggest solutions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply put: The "LAST" is the reason. It doesn't "copy" the value though. It aggregates the values to the last existing value along the dimensional hierarchy specified.

The question is: What SHOULD that Saldo show? What is the real business rule?

Also lastly: Using technical column names and ALL UPPER CASE COLUMN NAMES in the BMM layer shouldn't be done. The names should be user-focused, readabla and pretty. Otherwise everybody has to go and change it 50 times over and over in the front-end.

Comment: The last should show the revenue for given date. It should show aggregated values for April 2014 only, not April 2016. I appreciate you pointed upper case column names, this I will change as soon as this problem is solved

Comment: The problem isn't this easy to solve based on your current input as it all depends on how your RPD is built in detail

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. What details do we need? In the image above I pointed out that it is aggreagated based on dimensions as last(sum(saldo)). What I dont understand is why I am getting revenues for April 2015 in April 2014 columns. Don't year and month columns filter it out?

Comment: It has to do with the whole construction of the RPD in terms of dimensional hierarchies and especially the time dimension and time hierarchy.

Comment: I saw you're at university - out of curiosity: are you doing this for self-study?

Comment: Chris, I was at university two years ago when I created a profile here. Now I work in a company that uses OBIEE and one of my tasks includes working with it as a developer. OBIEE is very new where I work so it took quite a long time to learn how to use it. I will edit my profile now, glad you mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year since I posted this question,but a fix for this incorrect representation of data was added today. In the previous version of rpd, we used another alternative solution to this by creating two measure columns of saldo ( saldo_year and saldo_month) and setting level for them at year and level respectively and using them both in an analysis. This was a temporary solution until we did the second version of our rpd since we realized that structure of the old one wasn't completely correct and  it was easier and less time consuming to make it from ground and create a new one than to fix the old one.

So as @Chris mentioned, it was all about correct time dimension and hierarchies. We thought we created it with all requirements met, but recently we got the same problem in our analyses. Then we figured out that we didn't set id columns  as primary key in month and quarter logical levels. After we got the data we want. If anybody faces this kind of problem, then the first thing to check in rpd is how the time dimension and hierarchy is defined, how logical levels and primary keys and chronological keys are set in hierarchy.